# How to make form input value in A to appear in B using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to type something in form input **a** and display it in form input **b** and in div **c**?

Let's assume that I enter value **100** in form input **a**, how can I make it to appear in form input **b** and **div c** as I type?

The code below is not working properly:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('[name="b"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="a"]').val($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="a" name="a" value="">
<input type="text" id="b" name="b" value=""/>

<div id="c" class="c"></div>
```

Comment: Well your code takes `b` and puts it in `a`. You use `change` which fires when they move focus from the input. You want to use `input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the event listener to the input whose name is `a` instead of `b`:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('[name="a"]').on('input', function() {
        $('[name="b"]').val($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="a" name="a" value="">
<input type="text" id="b" name="b" value=""/>

<div id="c" class="c"></div>
```